# JQuery UI confirmation dialog $_POST

Tags: jquery, post, jquery-ui-dialog

The script is:

```
function cDelete() {
    $("#dialog-confirm").dialog({
        resizable: false,
        height: 240,
        modal: true,
        buttons: {
            "Delete item": function () {
                $(this).dialog("close");
                $('form#someform').submit();
            },
            Cancel: function () {
                $(this).dialog("close");
                return false;
            }
        }
    });
    return false; 
}
```

and the form elements:

```
<form id="someform" action="somefile.php" method="POST">
    <button name="delete" type="submit" class="cancel" onclick="return cDelete();">Delete</button>
    <input type='checkbox' class='toggle' value='$article_id' name='page-id[]'>
</form>
```

In php file i check the data like this:

```
if (isset($_POST['delete']) && isset($_POST['page-id'])){}
```

So here is the problem: 
the script sends POST of checked checkboxes (`$_POST['page-id']`) correctly but it doesn't send POST of pressed button (`$_POST['delete']`). Ok It does but only when i put into form hidden input like: <`input type="hidden" name="delete">`.

I'd like to make this work whitout hidden input. Im trying to solve this but still no results.
Maybe someone could help me?

And the second question: Is it possible that script will be working onsubmit(form) instead onclick(button)?

Comment: It does not send the button value because using the dialog introduces asynchronism, so that it is not the clicking on the button that actually sends the form – you calling the form’s `submit` method is. And using `onsubmit` won’t change that. If you don’t want the hidden field to be part of your HTML, then you could insert it dynamically.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for answer. I dont know what is better : dynamically insert or hidden input, but in this case I think it doesn't matter what will I pick. Important is to make it work. Anyway I'll try with dynamically insert. PS i know onsubmit won't change that. I just wanted to use onsubmit becouse I think it's better way to validate form than onclick (some people use enter) especially when you have few submit buttons or input[submit]. But in this case i have only 1 so enter works exactly like click so I'll stay by onclick i think. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

you need to define name and value for button, this will send the value of button too

```
<button name="delete" type="submit" class="cancel" onclick="return cDelete();" value="Delete">Delete</button>
```

For second question check this out

[Jquery trap form submit()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9065972/jquery-trap-form-submit)

Comment: Sory I didnt specify my form declaration. I'll correct it. It has ofcourse action and method. Like I said I recive POST of checked checkboxes ($_POST['page-id']) but I cant receiving POST of pressed button ($_POST['delete'])

Comment: @RysQ you need to define `value` to button

Comment: I've defined value to button but it's still not working. Thanks for link

Comment: @RysQ I tested and it definitely sends the button value. Also check your closing tag for `form` element you put `div` instead

Comment: I do not know how you get button value. I just made another document only with script, form and print_r($POST). Double check of form elements attributes, classes, ids. Still nothing. But i think i've got answer under my post. Anyway thanks for answers. Ps.. yep i closed form with `div` accidentally (on this listing). I'll correct it