# Prevent clicking submit on form from propagating to click handler

Tags: jquery, forms, click, submit, event-bubbling

I have a click event that slides a form up into view. I'm also using .toggle to slide the form back down. The problem I have is that when the user clicks the submit button on the form the form slides back down as if the .toggle was triggered.

```
// Slides the contact form up from the footer
$('#show-form').click(function (e) {
e.stopPropagation();
$('#get-started-form').hide('slide', {direction: 'down'}, 750);
$(this).next('#get-started-form').stop().toggle('slide', {direction: 'down'}, 750);
```

});

I tried to use .stopPropogation on the forms' submit button as follows;

```
$('#gform_submit_button_1').click(function(event) {
event.stopPropagation();
```

});

Comment: Possible duplicate:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9065972/jquery-trap-form-submit

Comment: What is the html? Can you send a jsfiddle or codepen? Seems like the button click is propogating as a form click too, but can't be sure without seeing the hmtl structures you are referencing in the script.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/xbztkbxx/8/

Clicking #show-form causes the gravity form to slide up in to view. When the submit button is clicked the trigger event is fired and the form slides back down out of view. It should stay open until  #show-form is clicked again so the user can see the confirmation or validation errors.

*I see that Gravity forms is adding a trigger event to the document which is probably what's causing the problem.

*See the javascript for the code that I tried to use to prevent the Gravity forms trigger from affecting the toggle.

*Using jQuery UI to slide up and down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the page is reloading on submit and the validation messages are not showing because as the page reloads it "closes" or loads closed. Try validation and submitting via ajax rather than the form post.